# trying to reflect the effect a change to the original variable (call by reference)

Tags: c++, vector

I have defined a vector which consist of pairs and vectors. For better readability, I do this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
  vector< pair<int, vector<int> > > v;
  vector< pair<int, vector<int> > >::iterator it;
  void bar() 
  {
    for( it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++ ) {
      if ( 10 == (*it).first ) {
          vector<int> a = (*it).second;   // NOTE
          a[0] = a[0]*2;                  // NOTE
      }
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  foo f;
  f.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I assign `(*it).second` to a variable `a` so that I manipulate easily. Problem is, when I change the value of `a`, the original vector `v` doesn't change. I can resolve that changing `a` to `(*it).second` every where in the loop. However this will make the code hard for reading.

Is there any way to reflect the changes in `a` to the original `v`? I have to say call by reference like this

```
vector<int> a = &(*it).second;
```

doesn't work

Comment: Saving an iterator as a member and then using it while looping like this is very fragile and completely thread-unsafe. Any recursion or parallel execution could break this. A slight improvement would be to have a local iterator for the loop and setting the member `it` to this local value at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `a` as a reference:

`vector<int>& a = (*it).second;`

Ampersand in `std::vector<int> a = &(*it).second;` is being parsed as adress-of operator and `a` isn't a pointer - that's why it doesn't work/compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value of the original vector only when you take it into a reference.
But instead in your code you are creating a copy of it and changing that copy which does not effect the original vector.

your `vector<int> a` should be a reference instead.

```
vector<int> &a...
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all: there is no code which demonstrates how do you fill the `v` member and when you initialize `it`. just make sure that you have a valid `it` after all (remember that, all iterators into vector may invalidate after `v` modifications)

and the second: the correct line should be like this

```
vector<int>& a = it->second;
```

(you take an address instead, and your snippet even wouldn't compile)